# Vertically align images to bottom in gallery, only if the heights vary

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'm building an image gallery, and have run into a problem.  If the image labels are all the same length, they align perfectly, but if the label is longer than one line, it pushes the image up instead of creating more white space beneath.  How can I fix this?

I want the images to all align to one row, and the text to align from there, downward.

I tried putting this into a jsfiddle but for whatever reason I can't get it to work...  Here is the HTML making this

```
<div class="thumbrow">
    <div style="min-width:400px;" class="thumbrow">
        <div style="width:100px;" class="thumbs">
            <div style="width:100px;" class="imgbox">
                <a target="_blank" title="Hydrangeas" rel="lightbox[test]" href="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/Hydrangeas.jpg">
                    <img width="100" height="75" src="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/thumbs/Hydrangeas.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>Hydrangeas</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100px;" class="thumbs">
            <div style="width:100px;" class="imgbox">
                <a target="_blank" title="Chrysanthemum" rel="lightbox[test]" href="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
                    <img width="100" height="75" src="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/thumbs/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>Chrysanthemum</p>
       </div>
       <div style="width:100px;" class="thumbs">
            <div style="width:100px;" class="imgbox">
                <a target="_blank" title="Lighthouse" rel="lightbox[test]" href="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/Lighthouse.jpg">
                    <img width="100" height="75" src="http://jacobraccuia.com/test/wp-content/uploads/gallery/test/thumbs/Lighthouse.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>Lighthouse</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.thumbgal .thumbs {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.imgbox {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}   
.thumbrow {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbs p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Help please :D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to your problem, if you don't need the full text of the image to be shown, could be to cap the text at a certain width and add elipses if it overflows.

This will be in place of breaking the word to wrap it, and will keep the height of the labels to one line.

```
.thumbs p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 100px; /* Some width */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit: On a closer look, from the code given. I tried it out in a fiddle and it works fine for me. I just added a float and some margin to the `.thumbs`. http://jsfiddle.net/nKkWX/

Answer (score 0):

hi I think you mis to add style in your `.thumbs` *check* [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/nKkWX/1/)

```
.thumbs {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: same problem as ultranaut's solution.  the pictures don't align right if they are different sizes.

Comment: hi pls. check my update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/nKkWX/2/) correct me if im wrong, what you want to achieve is whatever the `height` of the image always the `text` underneath the image always align with othere text I am right or wrong?

Comment: I want the height of the images to all align from one point, with the excess height pushing all images downward.  Beneath each image, I want the text to push downward for new lines.  So the bottom of the image and the top of the text are always in line for each new image.  Currently, either the text pushes the image up, with the bottom of the text aligned, or the image pushes the text down, with the top of the image aligned.

Comment: yes, but then my original problem still exists, where the text pushes the image upward when it moves to a new row.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think to achieve what you want with pure `css and html` only maybe you need the help aether `jquery` or `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Set your `thumbs` divs' `display` value to `inline-block` and vertically align them to the top:

```
.thumbs {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/Pskqb/).

Comment: This doesn't help me if the images have different sizes.  I want the images to all align to the bottom, and for the text to align directly underneath the image, but push downward!